# Prediction using Random Forest in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest

I created a model in R for my df as

```
fit <- randomForest(y ~ x1 + 
                     x2 + x3 + 
                     x4+ x5+x6+ x7+x8, 
                     data = data_train,ntree=35,
                     keep.forest=FALSE, importance=TRUE)
```

gives result as

```
 Call:
  randomForest(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 
 +      x3 + x4 + x5 + 
   x6 +      x7 + x8, data = 
data_train, ntree = 35,      keep.forest = FALSE, importance = TRUE) 
           Type of random forest: regression
                 Number of trees: 35
   No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        Mean of squared residuals: 2901510
                % Var explained: 53.45
```

but while I am predicting using

```
p <- predict(data_test, fit, type='prob')
```

Shows error

```
Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, 
allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  : 
 y should be a univariate time series
```

When I am using

```
predict(fit, newdata= data_test)
```

Showing error

```
Error in predict.randomForest(fit, newdata = data_test) : 
 No forest component in the object
```

how can I solve this.. I am new in using RandomForest in R

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Why do you have `keep.forest = FALSE`? Try changing that to `TRUE` and re-attempt your second prediction approach.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 1):

As @bzki suggested By putting keep.forest = TRUE
It works fine